# Asp.Net Core - Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'

Tags: c#, mysql, sockets, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am experiencing a failure with my Asp.Net Core 1.1 app running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Usually, after a period of inactivity, when I click somewhere on a loaded site to trigger a controller, the website does not finish loading. I see the controller call timing out after 15 minutes on a first function which is supposed to fetch an object from a database (even though MySql timeout is set to 2 minutes in the connection string):

```
   at Frontend.Repository.WebsiteSettingsRepository.Find(String id, Boolean getRelated)
   at Frontend.Controllers.HomeController.Index()
```

This is the full exception I am getting:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
  An unhandled exception has occurred: Connect Timeout expired.
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Connect Timeout expired. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(IPAddress address, Int32 port, AsyncCallback requestCallback, Object state)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.BeginConnect(IPAddress address, Int32 port, AsyncCallback requestCallback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5 beginMethod, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.ConnectAsync(IPAddress address, Int32 port)
   at MySql.Data.Serialization.MySqlSession.<OpenTcpSocketAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.Serialization.MySqlSession.<OpenTcpSocketAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MySql.Data.Serialization.MySqlSession.<ConnectAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ConnectionPool.<GetSessionAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.<CreateSessionAsync>d__57.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.<OpenAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySqlRelationalConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.MySqlQueryingEnumerable`1.MySqlEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass20_0`1.<CompileQueryCore>b__0(QueryContext qc)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at Frontend.Repository.WebsiteSettingsRepository.Find(String id, Boolean getRelated)
   at Frontend.Controllers.HomeController.Index()
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
```

I use the dependency injection to pass the context to the repositories:

```
    services.AddDbContext<DatabaseConnector>(options =>
    {
        options.UseMySql(mysqlConfigString);
        options.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(CoreEventId.IncludeIgnoredWarning));
    });
```

in the constructor:

```
    public WebsiteSettingsRepository(DatabaseConnector dbContext)
    {
        _db = dbContext;
    }
```

The DatabaseConnector has a few DbSets, for example:

```
public DbSet<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
```

As far as I understand, the database context also uses the default memory cache for temporary results.

The database is used for fetching details only for the frontend side, so the amount of the transferred data is small (the core data is stored in a separate distributed cluster).

I was suspecting the number of the connections in the pool might be exceeded, but this should give a different error. There should not be any connection leak, because the connection is never explicitly opened. Now, I am thinking it might be OS-specific. Most of the times the website works fine though. Any ideas? I already tried scaling up a vm.

[Update]

The controller's code, it's not even async, it only uses multiple repositories:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var activity = new CustomLog("HomeController.Index");
        try
        {
            (a couple of non-db lines, the next one throws)
            var newsSpeed = _settingsRepository.Find(WebsiteSetting.NewsSpeed.ToString());
            (...)
            if (newsSpeed != null && newsSpeed.Value != null)
            {
                tableConfig.NewsScrollSpeed = int.Parse(newsSpeed.Value);
            }

            (a lot of similar stuff there...)

            return View(tableConfig);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            activity.Finish(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

SettingRepository is set through DI in a controller's constructor and looks like this:

```
private readonly IGenericRepositoryNamed<WebsiteSettingsModel, WebsiteSettingsViewModel> _settingsRepository;
```

It's created in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddScoped<IGenericRepositoryNamed<WebsiteSettingsModel, WebsiteSettingsViewModel>, WebsiteSettingsRepository>();
```

Comment: Please post the code that is causing this in your controller method. I can remember getting into a similar issue when an awaited db call goes on after a view was passed to the user. I don't think it's OS related.

Comment: @Vahid - updated, is that enough?

Comment: Connection string has both `Connect Timeout` and `Command Timeout`. They apply to time outs that occur when connecting to the database and while executing query respectively.  Check if they are set as needed for you